# Dynamically changing the MKAnnotationView according to zoom level in MapKit?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

Currently, I am calculating the zoom level each time `mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion` is called.  I would like to display one set of annotations at say, zoom level 5, and another set of annotations at zoom level 10.

Within the MKMapViewDelegate, there is a method to return an annotation view: `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`,
but this isn't called with the frequency I would need to swap out the view according to the zoom level.

So how can I make the annotation views display more dynamically in response to the change in zoom level / visible region?

Comment: When you calculate the zoom level, have you tried `removeAnnotations` and then `addAnnotations` and ensure that in `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` you check which set of annotations you want to be displayed?

Comment: Thank you.  This appears to be the right way to go about this.  I just did a test and it works.